# Yup minimum age validation with day month year values from dropdown

Tags: yup

Using select control to pickup day, month, year of dob

How to validate min age say 18 in yup itself

```
      dateOfBirth: Yup.object().shape({
        day: Yup.string().required('day is required'),
        month: Yup.string().required('month is required'),
        year: Yup.string().required('year is required')
      })
```